# How to pass an array of objects to a modal page in Ionic?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have an array of objects

```
cart = [{name: 'Test', description: 'Test'}, {name: 'Test', description: 'Test'}];
```

I want to pass this to a modal page when a button is clicked. My code is set up as such:

```
openCart(){
    let data = this.cart;
    let modal = this.modalCtrl.create(CartPage, data);
    modal.present();
}
```

In the modal page I'm trying to get log the data as

```
console.log(navParams.get('data'));
```

But this returns my data as undefined. How can I pass an array of objects from my homepage to my modal page and retrieve the data? Ideally I would like to store the data passed into a variable and show 'name' and 'description' on the html view page.

Comment: Found a solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
openCart(){
    let modal = this.modalCtrl.create(CartPage, { data: this.cart });
    modal.present();
}
```

Then you should be able to get the array by calling:

```
navParams.get('data');
```

or

```
this.navParams.get('data');
```

if calling from outside of the constructor.

Comment: Worked! Thank you! If you don't mind be asking, why didn't my method word? The data must be passed as an object?

Comment: You're welcome! Exactly, it must be passed as an object. Be sure to upvote my answer if you found it useful.

Answer (score 0):

In the model page you should try like this:

```
 console.log( this.navParams.get('name'));
```

> **Note**: while getting data, fetch the value by using key

Comment: This still gives undefined, but the robbannn's method worked. Thanks for the help.